# wagtail, error converting images to jpegs - invalid operation jpeg

Tags: wagtail

I'm trying to output my image as a jpeg, using format-jpeg and this in my template -

`{% image card.specific.hero_image fill-320x150 jpeg-quality-90 format-jpeg as card_image %}`

I get this error message

> InvalidFilterSpecError at /admin/pages/3/edit/preview/
>
> Unrecognised operation: jpeg

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example in de docs is:

```
{% image page.photo width-400 format-jpeg jpegquality-40 %}
```

So `jpeg-quality-90` should read `jpegquality-90` AND `format-jpeg` comes before `jpegquality-90`.